# Native Emberjs views or jQuery=UI widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, ember.js

I am planning to create a resizble divs like the same provided by jQuery-UI. the question is which is better integrate the jQuery-UI widget the same way provided by this article

http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2012/03/10/using-ember-js-with-jquery-ui/

or I must consider building it from scratch using Emberjs views?

what are advantages and disadvantages of each of both methods, in terms of performance, rendering, and data exchange.

Thanks

Comment: from scratch you may end up doing same...use luke's method only...

Comment: I think Luke's method is very effective, I read through the whole thing it seems very good

Answer (score 0):

Go with JQueryUI unless/until you have compelling reasons to build your own.  No need to spend time reinventing anything that's already available for use.